# How to use recaptcha for my first project in php

Tags: php, mysql, recaptcha

Since, I'm new to php. I just want to ask how to implement ReCaptcha for my first project http://www.textlinkgravity.com

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: [WhatHaveYouTried? Any Code??](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try googling first before you ask on SO. Often your question has been answered before: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/php

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry about my question, the first thing comes into my mind is to ask here immediately instead of googling it. Anyways, thanks to all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use re-captcha you 'just' have to follow the instructions on the [re-captca website](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/php). It's a step by step 'how to'. You should be able to make it works if you follow all the steps

Comment: +1 Try adding a few key steps/instructions from the link here to supplement your answer.

Comment: This is better suited as a comment (once you gain comment privileges at 50 rep). Generally on SO, little text with a link isn't a well formulated answer. You should include code samples or other explanations. :)

Comment: thanks guys, since I'm very new here in SO. I just sign up here.